# Best practices to load data in junction object

Tags: migration

I know how to load data in Junction Object using Import Wizard and Data Loader. I also know we require either Salesforce IDs or External IDs from the 2 M-D/Lookup tables.

My question is, how to identify which method of data load should be used i.e.

- When should I use External IDs?
- When should I use Salesforce IDs?
- What is the process/behavior when done with different tools (Data Loader, ETL - Informatica to be specific)

Answer (score 1):

Junction objects may be created either by data load or often times programmatically via an apex controller.
I have seen use cases where a custom vf page was needed to be able to create a many to many relationship where the user can pick out the records to relate and the controller creates the junction object records.
Salesforce Ids should be used when available. If they are unavailable External Ids can be used. To relate records using External Ids in Apex, Insert or Update/Upsert can be used. However when matching via Data Loader, the records must be upserted and the mapping files need to map the use of external ids.

```
Account acc = new  Account(ExternalId__c='abcdef');
Contact con = new Contact(Name='Smith');
con.Account = acc;
Insert con;
```

Data Migration is a classic use case where you may need to load in junction object records to relate records.   You will not have the salesforce ids when you export the data from the source system but possibly will have primary keys which can be used to join up the import the relationships into salesforce by marking them as External Ids and using Upsert.